# How to SELECT columns without including them in GROUP BY access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

My sample sql query

```
 SELECT EID,p,p1,p2,p3 FROM table 1 GROUP BY EID;
```

Giving error not part of aggregate function.I wanted to group by only **EID** not all other **p,p1,p2,p3**. How do i specify that in sql query.

Comment: You need to use aggregates on p, p1, ... Otherwise how sql server will know how to "merge" them ?

Comment: @vuyy1182 That's possible on Postgresql (and MySQL too, albeit implemented poorly). That's not possible in SQL Server nor Microsoft Access. See: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/08/postgresql-recognizing-functional.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most dialects of SQL, you have to specify *which* column you want, if the column is not in the `group by` clause.  For instance, maybe you want the minimum value:

```
SELECT EID, min(p), min(p1), min(p2), min(p3)
FROM table 1
GROUP BY EID;
```

Or, if you wanted all the values from a particular record, use `first` or `last`:

```
SELECT EID, first(p), first(p1), first(p2), first(p3)
FROM table 1
GROUP BY EID;
```